# How to set custom font for Windows Phone webview control

Tags: windows-phone, microsoft-edge, custom-font

Windows Phone 10 does not support custom font for webview control. Edge browser also does not support custom font. E.g. Burmese font Zawgyi.

How to set custom font for webview control in Windows Phone application?

Answer (score 0):

To support custom font in webview control:

(1.) Create the CSS with embedded font

```
    body, a, p, span, div, textarea {
      font-family: MyCustomFont;
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: MyCustomFont;
      src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAXXXXXXXXXXX......) format('woff');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
     }
```

(2.) Inject jQuery and CSS at WebView_NavigationCompleted method

```
 private async void MyWebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
 {
    // Inject jQuery file which located at local
    StorageFile jquery = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///JavaScripts\\jquery-1.10.2.min.js"));
    string jquery_string = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(jquery);
    await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { jquery_string });


    // Inject custom font embedded CSS 
    StorageFile myfontcss = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///CSS\\mycustomfont.css"));
    string myfontcss_string = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(myfontcss);

    myfontcss_string = myfontcss_string.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\t", ""); //.Replace("'", "&#39;").Replace("\"", "&#34;");
    string cssRef = "$(\"<style id='myfont' type='text/css'>" + myfontcss_string + "</style>\").appendTo('head');";

    await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { cssRef });

  }
```